# Why date field is getting saved as null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Why ***@OpeningDate*** is getting saved as NULL even though I am doing this.

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCaseANDHearingDetails]

    @HearingDate    datetime,

    @IsOpeningDate  bit= null,
    @OpeningDate date= null,

AS  
Begin  
      IF(@IsOpeningDate = 0)
      Begin
          Set @OpeningDate= (Select Convert(varchar, @HearingDate, 106))
      End

      Insert Into Hearings
      values (@HearingDate, @OpeningDate)


End
```

Even though I am calculating it and hearing date is not null but why OpeningDate is getting saved as NULL.

Comment: Include your call to `dbo.InsertCaseAndHearingDetails`.

Answer (score 3):

`@HearingDate != NULL` will not work. The result of this comparison is always `unknown`. Use `@HearingDate is not null` instead.

Because the variable `@HearingDate` is not initialized, it would have a `null` value.

Also, the variable `@OpeningDate` wouldn't be set to `Select Convert(varchar, @HearingDate, 106)` because the `if` condition evaluates to `unknown`.

Hence, when you select values from the table they would be `null`.

Edit:

```
@IsOpeningDate  bit= null
...
IF(@IsOpeningDate = 0)
```

This condition evaluates to `unknown` too as this is doing `0 = null`. You **cannot** compare with `null`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "The result of this comparison is always unknown"?

Comment: but i changed the condition to by adding another BIT column
if (@IsOpeningClosingDate = 1)

Comment: and put this in if conditon block 
Set @OpeningDate= (Select Convert(varchar, @HearingDate, 106))

Comment: @roryap SQL has three Boolean values: TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN. Comparisons to NULL normally result in UNKNOWN. (There are exceptions when `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.) Think of NULL as being some value, but we don't know what it is. `@x = NULL`.We don't know what `NULL` is, so being equal to `@x` is unknown.

Comment: @vkp, `@HearingDate` is a parameter and is initialized by the invocation of the stored procedure. `@IsOpeningDate` and `@OpeningDate` are optional parameters with default values.

Comment: @RossPresser -- Why are you yelling so much?  If you want to emphasize, surround your text in single asterisks (for italics) or double asterisks (for bold).

Comment: You **cannot** use `!=` to compare something to `NULL`. You must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. Using `=`, `!=`, or any other comparison **whatsoever** will always return `NULL`, which is never a true value. Does not matter if your fields are `bit`, `integer`, `varchar`, `xml`, or anything at all. **You cannot compare to `NULL`.** You can only test `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @roryap -- happy now?

Comment: @RossPresser -- No, I really don't care.  I'm just pointing something to you that might improve your future interactions on this site.  See this, among many others: https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you use the following at the start of the Proc.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

Basically *NULL* can't be compared, not even with itself, because this is not a value. If at all, you want the engine to treat it as one, you need to set off the `ANSI_NULLS` property. That said, I would prefer to go with @vkp's answer any day.

Based on your edit, it looks like the below condition is not met:

```
IF(@IsOpeningDate = 0)
```

and hence, it remains NULL.

Comment: "In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: Wasn't this question tagged under SQL-Server-2008 and SQL-Server-2012?

Comment: And the code will never be migrated to a future version of SQL Server?

Comment: Best practice is something else(which my answer also mentions) and downright denying something that actually exists is something else. My answer is perfectly valid for these two versions and I fully stick by it.

Comment: so what is the soultion in my case

Comment: @Juventustech - check my edit. You can try debugging by adding an `ELSE` part to it. If the `ELSE` branch is hit, you can verify my claim.

Comment: I checked, CONDITION is met

Comment: Inside the `IF` clause, try putting a `SELECT @HearingDate`. Are you getting a Non- NULL value?

Answer (score 0):

in the if condition why dont you check is null instead of comparing it to 0

Your query

```
IF(@IsOpeningDate = 0)
```

My suggestion

```
IF(@IsOpeningDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake to no mention parameters in Insert statement and since NULL were allowed so it inserted NULLs

Thanks for your help as it led me to figure out that what's actually going on.